# Balsamiq, how to put a button in a Datagrid

Tags: mockups, balsamiq

How can I put a button in a Data Grid in balsamiq? I'm using Balsamiq Mockups 2.2.9.

Comment: I don't think you can put a button in a data grid using the wiki formatting text, the best I found was to just place a button on top of the grid by dragging it on. It looks fine but doesn't automatically flow if you change the layout or size of the table.

Comment: I think this should be reopened as it is about a software tools commonly used by programmers; and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just know that a data grid allows to insert only radio buttons or check boxes. However, you may solve your question in below link,

http://blogs.balsamiq.com/ux/2010/07/15/mockup-tips-datagrids-and-specifying-interaction/

I'm not sure that in recent versions, whether it has any other available methods.

Comment: Still looks like you cannot add a button into a grid /table .   Have to just drag a button on TOP of grid  :(